# Python pandas add new column in dataframe after group by, based on emp-manager relation

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
testdf=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,3,4,16,17,2,52,53,54,55],\
                     'name':['Furniture','dining table','sofa','chairs','hammock','Electronics','smartphone','watch','laptop','earbuds'],\
                     'parent_id':[np.nan,1,1,1,1,np.nan,2,2,2,2]})

#testdfgroupby = testdf.groupby('parent_id')
#testdfobj=testdfgroupby.get_group(1)
testdf['parent_id_name'] = testdf.groupby('parent_id').transform(lambda x: testdf['name'] if (testdf['id']==testdf['parent_id']) else '')
```

Output of source dataframe is

```
id          name  parent_id
 1     Furniture        NaN
 3  dining table        1.0
 4          sofa        1.0
16        chairs        1.0
17       hammock        1.0
 2   Electronics        NaN
52    smartphone        2.0
53         watch        2.0
54        laptop        2.0
55       earbuds        2.0
```

And I am trying to achieve below output by adding new column , after finding "name" of parent_id to be displayed side by side

```
parent_id_name    id      name                parent_id
Furniture         3       dining table        1.0
Furniture         4       sofa                1.0
Furniture        16       chairs              1.0
Furniture        17       hammock             1.0
Electronics      52       smartphone          2.0
Electronics      53       watch               2.0
Electronics      54       laptop              2.0
Electronics      55       earbuds             2.0
```

Error coming like

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map` of `parent_id` with df from `id`, `name` columns

```
testdf.loc[testdf["parent_id"].notna(), "parent_id_name"] = (
    testdf.loc[testdf["parent_id"].notna(), "parent_id"]
    .astype(int)
    .map(testdf.set_index("id")["name"])
)

print(testdf)

   id          name  parent_id parent_id_name
0   1     Furniture        NaN            NaN
1   3  dining table        1.0      Furniture
2   4          sofa        1.0      Furniture
3  16        chairs        1.0      Furniture
4  17       hammock        1.0      Furniture
5   2   Electronics        NaN            NaN
6  52    smartphone        2.0    Electronics
7  53         watch        2.0    Electronics
8  54        laptop        2.0    Electronics
9  55       earbuds        2.0    Electronics
```